# Can we get a 'skip flag' button in the 10k review tools?

Tags: feature-request, review, flagging

Re the answer review page you reach by clicking on the number in this yellow square:

[image: Review]

I can't see a *Skip* option. The only way I can make answers disappear from this page is by flagging them in some way. At the moment there are a slew of answers to [How do I explain to a six year old why people on the other side of the Earth don't fall off?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94471/how-do-i-explain-to-a-6-year-old-why-people-on-the-other-side-of-the-earth-dont) that I don't feel need flagging and I can't get rid of them.

Am I missing some obvious way to get them off this page? If not, can we have a *Skip* option on this page?

Comment: What exactly are you saying? What answer review page? Late answers? Mod tool?

Comment: @Dimensio1n0: the page you get to by clicking in the yellow square shown in the picture. This yellow square appears in the tool bar on all pages (though presumably only at certain rep levels). The page is titled *Tools - Review*, but all the review pages seems to share the same title so this doesn't help much.

Comment: Oh, that must be a 10k mod tool, then.

Comment: I can flag as "has invalid flags" if I wish to disagree, but I can't see any option for "I don't care don't show me this again". Maybe that's deliberate :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is some confusion here, so let me clear some things up.

- [Review queues](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review) are accessible [from 500 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues). This starts with the [Late Answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers) and [First Posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) review queues, gets augmented by the [Suggested Edits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) and [Low Quality Posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts) queues at [2,000 rep](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), and finally [Close Votes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close) and [Reopen Votes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) at [3,000 rep](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). It is easily accessible by a link that says `review` on the top bar, between your gravatar and the search bar.

  [image: review link on top bar]

  In each review queue, you are given the option to skip each question you consider using a button on the upper right corner, which is next to the other 'action buttons'.

  [image: skip button on review queues]
- [Moderator tools](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools) are available to users with [10k reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and above. These tools include lists of posts with extreme votes, comments, views and edits, in-depth views at the closure, deletion and migration processes, and a few sundries. Most importantly (for this question), it also includes a page for dealing with certain types of [flags](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

  [image: Moderator tools flags page]

  This includes `Not an answer` and `Very low quality` flags on answers, and certain system-generated flags. I do not know for sure whether `Spam` and `Offensive, abusive, or hate speech` flags make it to this queue; I can't recall seeing one but they appear in the flagging dialog so they must end up there as well. `Flag to close` flags send the question straight to the Close Votes review queue, which can be seen by >3k users. `Other (needs ♦ moderator attention)` flags are *not* visible by 10k users; they are confidential and can only be seen by moderators ♦ and certain members of the Stack Exchange team ♦.

  This [Flags page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=flags) can also be accessed by clicking on the *yellow* number that sometimes appears between your gravatar and the `review` link.

  [image: review link on top bar]

  (An orange number can also appear, which links to the Suggested Edits review queue when it is not empty.)

  Flags in this page can be confirmed - you can re-flag the post, with either the same flag or a different one - or they can be deemed invalid. These are 'soft' votes: they are there to help moderators when they deal with the original flag (for more information, see [this MSO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96475)), but of course that makes them no less useful.

  [image]

---

With that out of the way, and in answer to John Rennie's question: no, it is not possible at present to skip flags. I imagine this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), as there is no real reason to skip such flags. If you don't want to deal with them, simply don't go to that page. If you think they're invalid, mark them as such.

Having a skip button makes particular sense in [places with a review queue overload problem](https://stackoverflow.com/review). Each reviewer has a finite number of votes per queue, and if a queue is overloaded it makes no sense to have reviewers spend time on posts they don't understand. Having a skip button streamlines the job by helping reviewers get to posts they *can* review quicker and not forcing them to deal with posts they *can't* deal with. This is mostly due to the linear, one-post-at-a-time way the review queues are presented. The flags page, on the other hand, shows all of them at once, so that flags you don't want to deal with are not in the way of fresh ones.

Having said that, there **is** a problem with the flags review queue, and it is that it takes a long time after you've handled a flag for the annoying yellow number in the top bar to go away. I first reported this [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/10k-tools-show-flag-counts-for-flags-i-cant-see) and then in MSO [back in September](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196775/the-flag-counter-in-the-10k-tools-should-reflect-the-posts-i-can-actually-see) as a bug in the flags page, and then [when the yellow number appeared in the top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212375/remove-the-flag-notification-in-the-top-bar-when-i-have-done-my-job-with-it/216113#216113). If you find this notification annoying, please go and show those threads some love!

Comment: Thanks. I take your point about the need for a *Skip* button, but the completer finisher in me finds it really annoying to have to leave flag notifications for the several days they take to expire. I would much prefer to dismiss all flag notifications even when I don't want to express an opinion. That way the only notifications I would see on that page would be new ones.

Comment: I see your point, but to be honest I would rather have the notifications go away when you've dealt with the flags, and then worry about skipping flags.